# Redirect output of forked python process to pipe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pipe, stdout

I want to write some logged process from a forked Python process to a parent, so I am using pipe pair for that:

```
rpipe, wpipe = os.pipe()

pid = os.fork()
if pid == -1:
    raise TestError("Failed to fork() in prepare_test_dir")

if pid == 0:
    # Child -- do the copy, print log to pipe and exit
    try:
        os.close(rpipe)
        os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stderr.fileno())
        os.close(wpipe)

        self._prepare_test_dir(test)

        sys.stdout.write(self.copy_log)
    finally:
        os._exit(1)

os.close(wpipe)

_, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)

# XXX: if copy_log is larger than PIPE_BUF (4-8k), everything
# then is going badly
outf = os.fdopen(rpipe)
self.copy_log = outf.read()

return os.WEXITSTATUS(status)
```

It doesn't work, nothing appears in `self.copy_log`. I have also tried to explicitly construct stdout object with `fdopen`:

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(wpipe, 'w')
```

Not working too. However if I put `print` before `dup2`:

```
if pid == 0:
    try:
        print 'HELLO'
        os.close(rpipe)
        os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stderr.fileno())
        ...
```

Copy log is successfully passed to parent and 'HELLO' is printed to controlling terminal. I presume that `print` somehow affects `sys.stdout` (with lazy initialization or whatever). Any ideas?

I use Python 2.6 and 2.7 on various Linux platforms.

Comment: You are doing it the hard way, use [module subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: I know about `subprocess`, but I have to use fork. Unfortunately, it is only option to guarantee that fds are closed. Also, `fork()` doesn't share anything, it performs copy-on-write on all writable segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be is not within pipe/dup2 related code but with `os._exit`. It is brutal way to kill python interpreter (but OK for forked processes so it won't touch "shared" objects), but it causes `stdout` and `stderr` not to be flushed, and data is lost.

I came to the following code in child:

```
try:
    os.close(rpipe)
    os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(wpipe, sys.stderr.fileno())
    os.close(wpipe)

    print 'aaaaaaaaa'
except:
    traceback.print_exc(20, sys.stderr)
finally:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    os._exit(1)
```